# Solution verification on Aluffi Chapter 0, Problem II.8.17

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, abelian-groups

**Problem** Assume $G$ is a finite abelian group, and let $p$ be a prime divisor of $|G|$. Prove that there exists an element in $G$ of order $p$.

**My solution** Let $g$ be any element of $G$. Since $\langle g \rangle$ is cyclic, it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} / |g|\mathbb{Z}$. Let $q$ be a prime divisor of $|g|$. Then the order of $g^{|g| / q}$ is $q$, and thus we showed that there is an element $h$ in $G$ of prime order $q$. Furthermore, the order of $G / \langle h \rangle$ is equal to $|G| / q$.

Since $G / \langle h \rangle$ is again finite and abelian, we can apply the conclusion above repeatedly to obtain the element in $G / \langle h_1 \rangle / \langle h_2 \rangle / \cdots / \langle h_n \rangle$ of order $p$, because $p$ is a prime divisor of $|G|$ and the quotient set eventually goes to trivial group.

Now we only need to show that if there is an element $a\langle h \rangle$ in $G / \langle h \rangle$ of order $p$, then there exists an element in $G$ of order $p$. It can be easily shown that the order of $a$ in $G$ is equal to $p$ from the fact that $(a \langle h \rangle)^p = (a^p) \langle h \rangle = \langle h \rangle$m and it closes the problem.

---

Although I am quite familiar with rigorous mathematics, I am completely new to algebra and not sure I am doing right. Are there any critical errors in my solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is an a corollary of Cauchy's Theorem. I guess it's not covered yet . . . What tools are we allowed to use, then?

Comment: Compare your proof with the standard ones, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2888310/proof-of-cauchys-theorem-for-abelian-groups).